# MvvmCross not binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing Pong with MvvmCross. The Paddles Y values change when holding the up and down buttons (buttons in the android view/activity - not keyboard buttons). However this is not being shown in the view (paddles stay in one spot, even though I can see in the console logs that the paddle has gone up or down).

Why are the paddles Y values not properly bound to the view?

Here is the code:

ViewModel:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;

using Pong.Core.ViewModels;
using Pong.Core.Models;

namespace Pong.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class GamePlayViewModel 
        : MvxViewModel
    {

        private string _hello = "Hello MvvmCross";
        public string Hello
        { 
            get { return _hello; }
            set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
        }

        private int _totalFramesBeenHad;
        public int TotalFramesBeenHad
        { 
            get { return _totalFramesBeenHad; }
            set { _totalFramesBeenHad = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => TotalFramesBeenHad); }
        }



        private PlayerPaddle _paddle1;
        public int Paddle1
        { 
            get { return _paddle1.Y; }
            set { _paddle1.Y = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Paddle1); }
        }

        private ComputerPaddle _paddle2;
        public int Paddle2
        { 
            get { return _paddle2.Y; }
            set { _paddle2.Y = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Paddle2); }
        }



        protected StandardBall StandardBall;

        public GamePlayViewModel()
        {
            _paddle1 = new PlayerPaddle();
            _paddle2 = new ComputerPaddle();
            StandardBall = new StandardBall();

        }

        public void UpdatePaddle1()
        {
            switch (_paddle1.DetectWallCollision())
            {
            case "upper":
                _paddle1.UpperWallHit();
                break;
            case "lower":
                _paddle1.LowerWallHit();
                break;
            case "none":
                _paddle1.MoveOneFrame();
                break;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateBall()
        {
            if (StandardBall.DetectWallCollision()) StandardBall.HandleWallCollision();
            StandardBall.MoveOneFrame();
        }

        public void SetPaddleDirection(string direction)
        {
            _paddle1.SetDirection(direction);
        }

        public void StopPaddle()
        {
            _paddle1.StopMoving();
        }
    }
}
```

child viewmodel (actual one used):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using Pong.Core.ViewModels;
using Pong.Core.Models;
using Pong.Droid.Views;

namespace Pong.Droid.ViewModels
{
    public class GamePlayViewModelAndroid : GamePlayViewModel
    {
        public readonly Timer _dispatcherTimer;

        public GamePlayView gpv;
        public GamePlayViewModelAndroid (GamePlayView gpv)
        {
            this.gpv = gpv;
            TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback (Tick);
            _dispatcherTimer = new Timer (timerDelegate, null, 0, 1000/Court.FPS);
        }

        public void Tick(object state)
        {
            UpdatePaddle1();
            gpv.move ();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using Cirrious;
using Cirrious.CrossCore;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using Pong.Droid.ViewModels;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Pong.Droid;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;

using Pong.Core.Models;


namespace Pong.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "!PONG!", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
    public class GamePlayView : MvxActivity
    {
        private GamePlayViewModelAndroid _viewModel;
        private Button _buttonUp;
        private Button _buttonDown;
        public GameView GameView;
        public LinearLayout ParentLayout;
        public LinearLayout ButtonsLayout;
        public int _paddle1y;
        public int _paddle2y;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            GameView = new GameView (this);
            _viewModel = new GamePlayViewModelAndroid(this);
            SetUpControls ();
            SetUpButtonEvents ();
            SetContentView(ParentLayout);
            DataContext = _viewModel;


            this.ClearAllBindings();
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<GamePlayView, GamePlayViewModelAndroid>();
            set.Bind(this).For(v => v._paddle1y).To(vm => vm.Paddle1);
            set.Bind(this).For(v => v._paddle2y).To(vm => vm.Paddle2);
            set.Apply();
        }

        void SetUpButtonEvents ()
        {
            _buttonUp.Touch += (s, e) =>  {
                var handled = false;
                if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
                    _viewModel.SetPaddleDirection ("up");
                    handled = true;
                }
                else
                    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up) {
                        _viewModel.StopPaddle ();
                        handled = true;
                    }
                e.Handled = handled;
            };
            _buttonDown.Touch += (s, e) =>  {
                var handled = false;
                if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
                    _viewModel.SetPaddleDirection ("down");
                    handled = true;
                }
                else
                    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up) {
                        _viewModel.StopPaddle ();
                        handled = true;
                    }
                e.Handled = handled;
            };
        }

        void SetUpControls ()
        {
            _buttonUp = new Button (this);
            _buttonDown = new Button (this);
            ParentLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
            ButtonsLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
            ParentLayout.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Horizontal;
            ButtonsLayout.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Vertical;
            ButtonsLayout.AddView (_buttonUp);
            ButtonsLayout.AddView (_buttonDown);
            ParentLayout.AddView (ButtonsLayout);
            ParentLayout.AddView (GameView);
        }

        public void move() {
            //GameView.paddle1y = _viewModel.Paddle1.Y;
            //GameView.paddle2y = _viewModel.Paddle2.Y;
            RunOnUiThread (() => GameView.Invalidate ());
        }
    }

    public class GameView : View {
        private Bitmap _paddleBmp;
        private int _paddle1x; 
        public int _paddle1y;
        private int _paddle2x; 
        public int _paddle2y;
        public GamePlayViewModelAndroid vm;
        public GamePlayView View;

        public GameView(Context context) : base (context) {
            SetPaddleBmp ();
//          this.ClearAllBindings();
//          var set = this.CreateBindingSet<GameView, GamePlayViewModelAndroid>();
//          set.Bind(_paddle1y).To(vm => vm.Paddle1.Y);
//          set.Bind(_paddle2y).To(vm => vm.Paddle2.Y);
//          set.Apply();
            //var set = this.CreateBindingSet<PolicySummaryCell, PolicyComponent<BasePolicy>>();
            //set.Bind(_periodOfInsurance).To(vm => vm.PeriodOfInsurance);
            //set.Bind(_title).To(vm => vm.Title);
            View = (GamePlayView)context;

        }

        void SetPaddleBmp ()
        {
            var paddlebmpTemp = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource (Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon);
            _paddleBmp = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (paddlebmpTemp, Paddle.Width, Paddle.Height, false);
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.DrawColor(Color.Aqua);
            canvas.DrawBitmap (_paddleBmp, _paddle1x, View._paddle1y, null);
            canvas.DrawBitmap (_paddleBmp, _paddle2x, View._paddle2y, null);
        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            SetUpCourt (w, h);
        }

        void SetUpCourt (int w, int h)
        {
            Court.Width = w;
            Court.Height = h;
            Court.UpperBound = 0;
            Court.LowerBound = h;
            Court.LeftBound = 0;
            Court.RightBound = w;
            ComputerPaddle.X = Court.RightBound - Paddle.Width - 20;
            _paddle2x = ComputerPaddle.X;
            _paddle1x = PlayerPaddle.X;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Pong.Core.Models
{
    public class Paddle
    {
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int VY { get; set; }
        public static readonly int Speed = 600;
        public static readonly int Height = 300;
        public static readonly int Width = 100;

        public void StopMoving()
        {
            VY = 0;
        }

        public void SetDirection(string direction)
        {
            if (direction == "up")
            {
                VY = -Speed;
            }
            else if (direction == "down")
            {
                VY = Speed;
            }
        }

        public string DetectWallCollision()
        {
            if (Y < Court.UpperBound)
            {
                return "upper";
            }
            if (Y > (Court.LowerBound - Paddle.Height))
            {
                return "lower";
            }
            return "none";
        }

        public void UpperWallHit()
        {
            StopMoving();
            Y = Court.UpperBound;
            Debug.WriteLine("You hit the top wall");
        }

        public void LowerWallHit()
        {
            StopMoving();
            Y = Court.LowerBound - Paddle.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine("You hit the bottom wall");
        }

        public void MoveOneFrame()
        {
            Y += VY/Court.FPS;//this should trigger the RaisePropertyChanged(() => Paddle1)
        }
    }

    public class PlayerPaddle : Paddle {
        public static readonly int X = 20;
    }

    public class ComputerPaddle : Paddle {
        public static int X;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use properties instead of fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that on the view, to bind a field to the viewModel programmatically, the field must be a property with a getter and setter. Just like this. In the view:

```
public int _paddle1y { get; set; }
public int _paddle2y { get; set; }
```

I don't know why this is the case. I think it's a bit of a bug in MvvmCross. But maybe there is a valid reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here, is that you're updating the Paddle.Y field, but the RaisePropertyChanged() called as your update the Paddle (on set).
See the difference?

Only if you'll set new instance of Paddle1 and Paddle2 property in GamePlayViewModel the setter will be called:

```
Paddle1 = new Paddle(); //will call the setter of Paddle1 property
Paddle1.Y = 90; //would not call the setter property
```

What you need to do is to call RaisePropertyChanged when you update the X and Y values of Paddle1 and Paddle2 properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling _paddle1 directly, call Paddle1 (and 2) so the RaisePropertyChanged event will get called.